# Make autocomplete work on a dropdown and have it fill contents of another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to get away from server-side controls for this because of the postback issue. I want to have two select boxes that are filled from a database. When the page loads I will have one combobox that will already be pre-filled from the database:

```
<select ID="cboCustomers">
   <option value="0">--Select a Sold-to customer--</option>
   <option value="1">Customer1</option>
   <option value="2">Customer2</option>
   <option value="3">Customer3</option>
   <option value="4">Customer4</option>
</select>

<select ID="cboShipTo">
   <option value="0">--Select a Ship-to customer--</option>
</select>
```

The first dropdown should have autocomplete enabled and when a value is selected, it should use AJAX to populate the second drop down list with Ship-to customers that are available for the selected Sold-to customers. I have an object that will take parameters and return the appropriate data. My question is how to accomplish the above. Can you provide me with some sample code or a jsFiddle that does what I am asking? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Had the same problem, but looking for internet found some resource.

first make the ajax sentence:

**Jquery**

```
$('#cboCustomers').onchange(function(){
 var $valueTofound = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "Your URL",
 data: Json.stringify({valueTofound : $valueTofound }), //You will pass data to code behind
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (data) {
 $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d), function () {
        $("#ddlRecords").append($("<option>  </option>").val(this['ID']).html(this['Name'])); //fill the dropdown
 });
 },
 error: function (msg) {
 //error
 }
 });
});
});
```

The codebehind C#

```
[WebMethod]
     public static string GetResultset(string valueTofound)
     {
       DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable(); //create a DataTable
       using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
     {
      try
      {
       SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("DO your Select", sqlConnection);
       sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);  //Fill the Datatable
       return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable); //return to Jquery
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
       throw ex;
      }
   }
}
```

Well that will help you or you have some other page:

[How to fill Dropdown from c#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/13350/bind-dropdownlist-in-Asp-Net-using-jquery.aspx)
[Other page](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/688228/Bind-Dropdownlist-in-ASP-NET-using-jQuery-AJAX)

Comment: Thanks @freak_droid, but what about the autocomplete/autofind while typing in the first dropdown?

Comment: @MichaelMahony I think is the same, becouse the onchange event is fire when your type or change the option, in my case I used that whitout auntocomplete, but I'm pretty sure is the same way.

Comment: My mistake the even is keyup or keypress